# Why does re.sub process backslashed escapes

Tags: python-3.x

The code is:

```
import re
p = r'\d\d\d'
s = '123'
```

But then:

```
re.sub(p,'abc\n',s)
re.sub(p,r'abc\n',s)
```

gives the same result, i.e. 'abc\n'. I didn't expect the second line to have this result. I thought it should be 'abc\n'. I went to Python doc and it says:

> re.sub(pattern, repl, string[, count, flags])
>
> ...repl can be a string or a function; if it is a string, any backslash escapes in it are processed. That is, \n is converted to a single newline character, \r is converted to a linefeed, and so forth...

So why does re.sub have this strange feature? I mean, shouldn't raw strings and normal strings always give different results in case of backslashed escapes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important part is

> any backslash escapes in it are processed.

This means that whether you pass `'abc\n'` or `'abc\\n'` doesn't matter, as the regex engine will convert the latter to the former *anyway*.

Comment: Yes, I know the result, but don't know why it is designed like that. If the programmer means '\n', then he just puts '\n' there. Otherwise, he puts r'\n' there. Mixing '' and r'' together is not a good idea. I don't see the motivation.

Comment: The thing is that both Python and the re module will interpret scape sequences. "\n", "\\n", r"\n" end up being the same for re: the first is converted by python, and the other two by re.